# Using external CSS link ref in a web component

Tags: javascript, css, web-component

I am trying to use Bulma from CDN inside a custom web component, but it doesn't appear to be working.

I have this for my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <my-element></my-element>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this for my js file:

```
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet()

sheet.replace('@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css")');

class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback(){
        let that = this
        let id = Math.random()
        this.id = id

        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
        shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet]

        let child = document.createElement('button')
        child.classList.add("button")
        child.innerText = id

        child.id = count

        shadowRoot.appendChild(child)

        this.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.target
            console.log(that.id)
            that.remove()
        })
    }
}

if(!customElements.get('my-element')){
    customElements.define('my-element', MyElement)
}

let count = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
for(i = 0; i <= count; i++){
    let el = document.createElement('my-element')
    document.body.appendChild(el)
}
```

What is notable is that if I use `sheet.replaceSync('button { color: green; }')` instead of `sheet.replace(...)`, it works fine. But why doesn't the external CSS link ref import work?

UPDATE: I realized I'm getting the following warning in the console:

```
index.js:6 @import rules are not allowed here. See https://github.com/WICG/construct-stylesheets/issues/119#issuecomment-588352418.
```

As a note, I am trying to use this approach so I can style multiple custom web components the same way, without needing to import the stylesheet multiple times.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any Cors errors in the Network tab in Devtools?

Comment: @zergski - no CORS errors, but I just realized I'm getting a relevant warning that I've added to the question.

Comment: I think `@import` rule cant be used dynamically, you can add the style sheet by appending `<link type="stylesheet" href="url">` to your document

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't apply the style from the link to my web component.

Comment: @import is not supported in adoptedStyleSheet.

Comment: *The CSS Working Group just discussed Add a note about the reasoning to forbid `insertRule(@import)`, or remove the condition?, and agreed to the following:

    RESOLVED: Disallow @import in all constructable stylesheet apis with a note that we're doing it to match current state of modules and this might relax in future*

Comment: Btw, you should create the shadow DOM in the constructor, not in the connectedCallback, because the latter one can be called multiple times (whenever e.g. adding or moving an element in the DOM).

Comment: `const shadowRoot` this variable is unnecessary. The shadowRoot is always available on the instance at `this.shadowRoot`.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to use a single instance for all your components, something like this:

```js
import bulmaStyles from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css';
const bulmaCSS = new CSSStyleSheet;
bulmaCSS.replaceSync(bulmaStyles);

export class Styles {
  static get bulma() { return bulmaCSS }
}
```

and then, in your components, import this class

```js
import { Styles } from 'path/to/Styles.js';

class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      // and use it in the constructor after creating the shadow DOM
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
      this.shadowRoot.adoptedStylesheets = [ Styles.bulma ];
    }
}
```

To be able to `import` the stylesheet's CSS into a variable, you need your build stack to support that. Webpack supports it e.g. with the help of `webpack-raw-loader`.

If you're not bundling your code, you will have to wait for CSS modules, or grab the styles from the DOM.

Comment: I am getting this error: 

Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: I tried working around this error by returning  `fetch` in the Styles.js `static get bulma(){...}` function then applying the returned CSS with `bulbmaCSS.replaceSync(bulmaStyles)`. I can see the styles in my component constructor, but the child that I append to my custom element is not taking that styling.

Comment: As mentioned, until CSS modules have landed in the spec and in browsers, you need a build stack like webpack along with `raw-loader` to be able to import CSS into a Javascript variable.

Comment: Just to double double check, I don't see a browser mentioned; You are aware adoptyedStyleSheets doesn't work in Firefox and Safari yet? https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_document_adoptedstylesheets

Comment: Last time I worked with it it didn't work because in Firefox you couldn't do `new CSSStyleSheet()` because it would result in an`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor.`.

Comment: If you care about why that takes so long: https://github.com/WICG/construct-stylesheets/issues/45

Comment: Okay -- It looks like I was misunderstanding your last sentence. I didn't realize when you said "wait for CSS modules" you were talking about a browser spec. I thought you meant that as long as I could see the CSS at the component level it would work (async/await, fetch). I'll play around with webpack.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Firefox has support for constructable stylesheets *behind a flag* now. In `about:config` set `layout.css.constructable-stylesheets.enabled` to `true`.

Comment: @connexo, thanks for the info. I couldn't find the WICG topic in 2 minutes.. This one is gold; it shows all 4 companies are working together on Web Components. Apart from technology this is the main reason why Web Components will succeed.